# how to set a base folder path in Grunt while building

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework, gruntjs, bower

I am using zend and grunt,bower. I kept the destination folder to ../public/dist. how can i prefix those urls with /dist so that they look like  /dist/styles and /dist/scripts in the dist/index.html when build? I tried various options and everything changes destination folder instead of prefixing.

{project-folder}/ui/app/{grunt file}
{project-folder}/public/dist/

Comment: How are you declaring your JS and CSS files in the view layer?

Comment: in the html file? `<script src="/scripts/blabla.js></script>` while in development as it will run as `http://localhost:port/` when run grunt serve. but i want the urls to be `<scripts src="{cutom_folder_name}/scripts/blabla.js">`

Comment: That's the output, how are you declaring those in the code?